# Nodejs equivalent in C# for streaming IO without buffering the content from requestContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-4.5, asp.net-core-2.0

Do we have the equivalent approach of streaming from one source to another destination without buffering it as we have in nodeJs.

In nodejs it emits different events while reading the chunk of data and it doesn't store in memory buffer.

What we have in C#? .net 4.5 or in .netcore2 ?

Nodejs sample with pipe option:

```
 var connector = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.pipe(response, {end:true});//tell 'response' end=true
});
request.pipe(connector, {end:true});
```

Comment: The same thing: `var readableStream = File.OpenRead("file1.txt"); var writableStream = File.OpenWrite("file2.txt"); readableStream.CopyTo(writableStream)`

Comment: Buffering will always be required in one way or another, in your nodejs example its only done implicitly by the pipe method. The data from the read stream must always be read in memory before it can be written somewhere else, even when the read buffer is just 4 or 8 kb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Tseng wrote in the comments, buffering is always needed.
I do something similar by streaming a file from Amazon S3 to an HTTP request in ASP.NET Core

```
    public static async Task<Stream> GetFile(string FileId)
    {
        try
        {
            TransferUtilityOpenStreamRequest request = new TransferUtilityOpenStreamRequest();
            request.BucketName = Config.S3BucketName;
            request.Key = FileId;

            return await S3Utility.OpenStreamAsync(request);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (Globals.Config.IsDebug)
                Console.WriteLine("[S3] " + e.ToString());

            return null;
        }
    }
```

and I have this on my main controller:

```
[Route("/files/{file_id}.{ext?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile(string file_id, string ext)
{
  return File(await Globals.GetFile(file_id), BakaMime.GetMimeType(ext));
}
```

The function `BakaMime.GetMimeType(ext)` is a function that gets a mime type from the extension, just an FYI.

Hope this helps show how you can stream data from one location to another.